# Checking if long is in array

Tags: java, arrays, string, long-integer, contain

I need to make sure that a certain long value isn't in an array. But for some reason, this isn't working...

```
!d.toString().contains(sq.toString());
```

I am sure I am getting something really backwards... but I can't figure out what!

Comment: Assuming that `d` is actually the array, then `.toString()` is not going to do what you're thinking -- it's not going to print out the elements of the array, and thus testing `contains` on that string is useless.

Comment: I would suggest checking for equality instead contains because: `"12345".contains("123")` returns `true` which is probably not what you want (assuming `d` and `sq` are string representations of the longs).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
!Arrays.asList(d).contains(sq);
```

Comment: Attention: this does not work for a `long[]`, only for object-type arrays (like `Long[]`).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the static methods in java.util.Arrays.  Your array will need to be sorted for the binarySearch() to work.