# Java - Checking whether an array of objects contains a certain string

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I'm trying to check whether an array of objects contain a specific string.

This is the constructor I have for Product object:

```
public Product()    
{
    name = "No name yet";
    demandRate = 0;        
    setupCost = 0;
    unitCost = 0;        
    inventoryCost = 0;
    sellingPrice = 0;        
}
```

This is the initialisation of the array:

```
 Product[] product = new Product[3];
```

I found similar questions here  [Checking if long is in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010044/checking-if-long-is-in-array) and here [Look if an array has an specified object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702853/look-if-an-array-has-an-specified-object). So I tried this code:

```
public boolean isAProduct(String nameOfProduct)
    //Returns true if a name has been found otherwise returns false
    {
        boolean found = false;
        int counter = 0;

        while (!found && (counter < MAXNUMBEROFPRODUCTS))
        {                
            if (Arrays.asList(product).contains(nameOfProduct))
            {                   
                found = true;
            }
            else 
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }        

        return found;
    }
```

But this doesn't work as it allows me to enter the same name for a product twice. So my question is, is what I'm attempting even possible? If not, how could I go about solving the problem?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is not how it works in Java. You need to walk through each "Product" object and compare "nameOfProduct" with "name" of "Product" object.

Comment: @Nambari Could you provide an example of how I would do that please? :)

Comment: I know you are doing class assignment, so I don't want to do code for you. But here is skeleton, Loop through Product[], get Product, then compare this Product--> "Name" with "nameOfProduct".

Comment: For future reference, "array of class objects" means something like ```Class<?> [] = new Class<?>[] { Object.class, Integer.class, System.class };```. You've just got an array of Objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a get method to your name of product inside the `Product` class to enable you to get the data you want to check on each iteration of the array. you cant just compare an object with a string without accessing the String.

**solution:**

create a getter method in your Product class

```
public String getName()
{
   return this.name;
}
```

Iterate to all the Product class and compare string by calling the getter method for the name of the product

```
for(int i = 0; i < current_size_product; i++)
{
  if(product[i].getName().contains(string))
    //true
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to solve the problem using your advice :)

Comment: Note that `getName()` is technically unnecessary. It's not required for your program to run; you can just use `product[i].name` if `name` is public. "Getter methods" help make it easier to develop large programs with less bugs, but they are not absolute requirements.

Comment: @immibis it is OOP you need to encapsulate your data.

Comment: It is not OOP, it is basic Java programming. When you know how to program, *then* you can learn OOP design principles.

Comment: @immibis While it is basic Java programming, It is also a uni assignment. The professor wants us to implement basic ideas of encapsulation and information hiding. One of the requirements being that instance variables are declared private.

Comment: Then do use a getter of course. I had no way of knowing that from your question and I guessed wrong.

Comment: @immibis Haha all good. I appreciate your input nonetheless :)